# Can I Ask Users To Follow a Page in Google+ In My Android App?

Tags: java, android, api, google-plus

I am trying to integrate Google+ into my application in Android but I cannot find a clear tutorial on how to let users follow my Google+ page. Does anyone know if this is possible at all and if so, how can I do that?

I discovered that Facebook does not allow liking a page within a Session, so I had to use a webview which redirected users to Facebook page and they have to login again.

If anyone has an idea, please help me. Thank you so much in advance!